# Redhat cluster Vs Pacemaker Vs Gluster Vs Sheepdog

Tags: centos, redhat, lvm, cluster, drbd

Changing the entire question as earlier one was very confusing.

I have been exploring different clustering system to run Virtual machines on two different machines on LAN with high availability.

Currently I am already using DRBD resource on two different machines on Primary/Secondary mode. In case the primary fails I manually promote the secondary to Primary and start the VM.

I also explored Gluster and looks good, however, I would rather prefer clustering over Gluster (user space FS).

So if anyone has idea which one would be better from ease of use prospective please I would be interested in.

Moreover, sheepdog project appears good, however, could not find much documentations/Howtos.

I am using Centos 6.

Comment: If it's already working with DRBD, but you are pursuing other alternatives then presumably it's not doing something you want.  What?

Comment: Well after some research I learned that it will be far more complicated System than what I am currently using.  Also I want have this fail over stuff in a relatively small setup only two machines one active another standby.

Comment: Another thing. So Redhat cluster should be compared with Pacemaker? I mean this looks like another cluster management software that provides high availability to resources?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go...

[The *full* RHEL KVM/HA tutorial...](https://alteeve.ca/w/2-Node_Red_Hat_KVM_Cluster_Tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have another question does it worth so much of efforts? Does it has any advantages over DRBD? Because setting up simple DRBD primary and secondary is pretty simple and quick with command line.